# Как сделать длинное название фирмы для сайта и короткое для мобильной версии?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Делаю простенький сайтик-визитку. Как сделать, чтобы для обычного сайта отображалось полное название фирмы, а для мобильной версии того же сайта - сокращённое?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам нужно 2 блока. Один с длинным названием (х) другой с коротким(y)

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">x</div>
<div class="d-block d-md-none">y</div>
```

подробнее тут [bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/)